# Why don't my jquery datatable get filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web-services

I am trying to fill my jquery data table from .asmx web service but throwing internal server 500 error.

why ?

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet=true)]
        //[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string getUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                basicoperation bop = new basicoperation();
               // Context.Response.Output.Write(bop.getUsers());
                DataTable dt;

                dt= bop.getUsers();

                dt.TableName = "usersDT";

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

                return json;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }


        }
```

this web service returns

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"ID":1,"UserName":"Yasir","Password":"123"},{"ID":2,"UserName":"asd","Password":"asdasd"},{"ID":3,"UserName":"Tester","Password":"123"},{"ID":4,"UserName":"rqads","Password":"12"},{"ID":5,"UserName":"asd","Password":"asda"},{"ID":6,"UserName":"asd","Password":"asda"},{"ID":7,"UserName":"hunain","Password":"123"},{"ID":8,"UserName":"hunain","Password":"123"},{"ID":9,"UserName":"username","Password":"123"},{"ID":10,"UserName":"","Password":""},{"ID":11,"UserName":"da","Password":"asd"},{"ID":12,"UserName":"sdas","Password":"asdas"},{"ID":13,"UserName":"","Password":""},{"ID":14,"UserName":"fdsf","Password":"sf"},{"ID":15,"UserName":"","Password":""},{"ID":16,"UserName":"","Password":""},{"ID":17,"UserName":"","Password":""}]
</string>
```

but still, it doesn't work.

here is my js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            .container-fluid
            {
                width: 40%;
                margin-left: 35% !important;
                margin-top: 10%  !important;
                border-style: ridge;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                border-width: 1px;

            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function save()
            {
                $.post(
                    "http://localhost:8373/himher.asmx/InsertUsers",
                    {name: txtUserName.value, pwd: txtUserPwd.value},
                    function(data, status)
                    {
                        alert(data);

                    }
                );
            }

            function show()
            {
                $.ajax({

                    url: 'http://localhost:8373/himher.asmx/getUsers',
                    method: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data){

                    $('#example').DataTable( {

                            data: data,                         
                            columns: [

                                  {"data": "ID" },
                                  {"data": "UserName" },
                                  {"data": "Password" },
                                    ]
                                }); 
                        }
                  });
            }

        </script>

    </head>
<body> 
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <label>User Name</label>
                 <input id="txtUserName" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <label>Password</label>
                 <input id="txtUserPwd" type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>    
        <br/>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-06">     
                 <button type="submit" onclick='save()' class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Register</button>
            </div>     

            <div class="col-md-06">
                <button type="submit" onclick='show()' class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Show</button>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am calling show() function on button click. I have spent a whole day on it and still, it doesn't work. Help would be highly appreciated in this regard.

Comment: You are loading jQuery 2 times...

Comment: Why are you sending xml? You are requesting `json` . Add some error handling

Comment: @Endless oh yeah, now it's a single link to jquery but still same error

Comment: @charlietfl: is it ? i have no further idea of it, I am naive so this is what i could do

Comment: help me correct the code if you can

Comment: @charlietfl can you edit the code so at least it starts working

Comment: Start by checking your server logs to see what is causing the 500

Comment: @charlietfl i did but it doesn't show anything in particular

Comment: oh yes it says, unexpected JSON toke, <

Comment: but still, can't figure out that from where it's coming @charlietfl